# Adding options (right-click) to icons on Gnome-Shell dock

Tags: unity, gnome, dock

Unity introduce a new costumization to the icons that consist on a little piece of code for the .desktop of the file, and then, when righ clicking on the icon on the Unity Dock, the options you define appears...

I wish to know if that could be done with the Gnome-Shell dock icons so I could have only the white Libreoffice Icon and then set the options to execute Writer Impress etc...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll have to wait at least for gnome 3.4 to get that feature in gnome-shell.

It's right now being worked on, see the [live.gnome.org webpage](https://live.gnome.org/ThreePointThree/Features/Jumplists) for further reference.

In the meantime, you can install the jump-list-gnome-shell-extension.

You can get it from [here](https://github.com/seiflotfy/gnome-shell-zeitgeist-extension)

This, however, will only show your recently and most used files, it won't enable you to launch writer or impress like Unity does.